# Import error when upgraded to scikit 0.15, warning for numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I upgraded scikit-learn from 0.14 to 0.15 and it gives a warning now

RuntimeWarning:scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:24: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility  from . import vonmises_cython.

I uninstalled earlier versions of numpy, scipy and scikit-learn as suggested in earlier posts and again installed all three numpy, scipy and scikit-learn 0.15 but warning still shows.
It works perfectly fine with scikit-learn 0.14

I am using Mac OSx 10.9.2.
To  uninstall, I used 
pip uninstall scikit-learn,

For install
pip install scikit-learn

After this I had also tried 
pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn as mentioned on the website
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html, but no success. 
The warning still shows.

Comment: Can you please update your question with information on your operating system and how you upgrade scikit-learn? Did you built from source or did you used a binary installer? If so which?

Comment: That error message seems to be coming from SciPy, not scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar warnings when I upgraded as well. I believe though I was seeing the warning when trying to unpickle a model I had pickled before the upgrade. I rebuilt the model and the warning went away.

Comment: I rebuilt everything form scratch that uses sckikit-learn but still the warning shows

Comment: Do (equivalent on Mac of) the following "sudo pip install scipy --upgrade"